# Shooting short clips vs. cutting long clips

Tags: ffmpeg, codec, compression

Say I want to create several short clips with the original encoding of a certain camera. Do I have to shoot the short clips directly or can I shoot a long clip and then cut it up using ffmpeg with the appropriate options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do either method.

## Short clips

- Take up less file space.
- Files are already cut.

## Long continuous shot

- Easier method when shooting, but more work in post.
- Easier to sync a continuous audio stream such as from an external mic.